# Are these default questions about events correct grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, syntactic-analysis

As you can see below, I created some default questions which are supposed to ask about events that either have happened or will happen in future(the gaps will be filled by different events such as "New Year" or "First World War" etc. ).

**Are any of the following questions poorly-formed**, provided that the ellipsis represents an event?

> Is ... an event?
>
> Where is ... started?
>
> Where has ... taken place?
>
> Where is ... finished?
>
> Who has participated in ... ?
>
> Who has organized ... ?
>
> For whom was ... advantageous or disadvantageous ?
>
> When is ... started ?
>
> When is ... finished ?
>
> What happens in ... ?
>
> What major events happened at ... ?
>
> What reasons made ... happen ?
>
> What type of facilities have been used in ... ?
>
> Which group of people have participated ... ?
>
> Which is the best source to gain more information about ... ?
>
> Why has ... started ?
>
> Why do we have to know about ... ?
>
> How long is ... ?
>
> How someone could take part in ... ?
>
> How many people have been involved in ... ?

Comment: I feel sure this is off-topic for at least one reason. One cannot conduct brainstorming exercises for creating lists. I am also a little unclear as to what is being asked.

Comment: @ws2, I removed the brain-storming/list-creation aspects, and tried to clarify what was being asked. How does it stand now?

Comment: @Dan Bron, I am so sorry guys for my poor English, it's not my mother tongue :( , and thanks alot dear Dan for your help to make it understandable, I am a graduate computer science student in Canada and this is some part of my thesis which is related to natural language processing (NLP)

Comment: @DanBron Some of them seem to work but other's don't. But this does sound awfully like a homework question to me.

Comment: @WS2, the question is, now, literally, "which of these questions work, and ***which don't*** (and *why*)?". Feel free to answer in that context. (Being homework isn't off-topic, per se.)

Comment: 'Where is the Battle of the Bulge started?' doesn't sound too idiomatic, but I suppose 'Where is the shelling of enemy trenches with gas shells started?' might work.

Comment: *"When is the Tour de France started?"* doesn't sound very idiomatic, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only proposed question I see which is a problem is the next-to-last one, where "someone could" should probably be "could someone". Otherwise, I don't see any that are particularly wrong, provided the verbs of the final sentences comply with rules about agreement between subject and verb.